# How can I replicate the test scenario in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am exploring `AWS RDS`, I have migrated the `MySQL` db to `RDS dbinstance`.

Now I want to test the `Amazon RDS - Multi-AZ Deployments For Enhanced Availability & Reliability feature.`

How can I replicate the test scenario where the primary Database failure doesnot cause any harm to the secondary server.

I have refferred to this link.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/05/amazon-rds-multi-az-deployment.html

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [RebootDBInstance API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RebootDBInstance.html) to force a fail over to the other AZ. Just set the `ForceFailover` parameter to `true`

Of course, you can also use the web console to Reboot your DB instance, as [described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RebootInstance.html).

--Seb

Comment: But it will be up in few seconds

Comment: I takes a few minutes to failover an RDS instance between AZs. What is your question ?

Comment: I am doing testing. I want to imitate the situation where the primary database fails and the secondary database instance comes into the picture. how can I do that as there is no option to stop the primary db instance

Comment: You can implement your test case exactly as I explained above.  Use the RebootDBInstance API with ForceFailover=true.  This will stop your  primary database instance and start the secondary one.  Then the database instance's DNS name will be switched to the secondary instance.  At that time the secondary instance will become your new primary database.  This mechanism will take a few minutes to complete.  Testing scenario involve to be sure your client app does not fail during the database failover and correctly reconnects to the secondary instance.

Comment: I want to do this using the console ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, as explained in my answer above, check the doc at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RebootInstance.html

Comment: But my application contains the db instance endpoint in its one of the file. will it be retained by secondary instance?

Comment: But the application was not able to access the database when i rebooted the db instance

Comment: Then you test succeeded :-) During the database failover, the database is not available for a few minutes.  Your application must try to reconnect until the database instance is available again.  This is the thing to test in this scenario - i.e. your application is able to failover gracefully.

Comment: yes, the RDS end point (i.e. DNS name) will remain identical after the fail over.

Comment: But i want that when primary DB fails secondary db should some in the picture. It should replace the primary db an application should work as intended

Comment: this is how RDS is designed to work.  When the primary DB fails, we start the secondary one and we switch the DNS name (endpoint) to the secondary.  Have a look at the documentation for the details : http://aws.amazon.com/rds/multi-az/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.It means during RDS fail-over, the client application will not lost connection but at the same time it won't be able to access the data as well and once fail-over completes, client will able to access the data.Right?

Comment: This is incorrect, applications will have a TCP connection drop and will require some intelligence to reconnect.  Reconnection will be possible within minutes.  It is up to application developers to decide how to behave during that short time frame (queue transactions, gracefully fail, ... depending on business requirements)

Comment: Okay.Understood. I have question regarding Multi-AZ.Can you please have a look at it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643782/behavior-of-aws-multi-az-rds-during-fail-over